# How can I make part of my page always be in the same position relative to the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I'm making a website, and I have a nav bar and a main content section, the nav bar is at the top of the screen and the main content in near the bottom of the screen.  However, if I change my screen height, the main content section stays in the same place, and it goes out of my browsers viewport/window and disappears, which is perfectly normal and expected. But what I want is for the main content section to always be at the same place at the bottom of the screen, no matter what the screen size/resolution/height is. How can I accomplish this?

My website is [jeffarries.com](http://jeffarries.com) and what I'm talking about is on my home page, if you need a visual.

I've used JavaScript, and I'm not very familiar with it.
I have no experience with jQuery, however I'm fine implementing a finished jQuery script.

Thanks for your Time and Energy!

Please let me know if any further information in needed.

---

**UPDATE:** Since this question appears to be unclear, take a visit to my website, you will see the text that says "here you can learn about me and my adventures", I want that text to appear at the bottom of the browser window when loaded, however, I want it to remain in usual flow, being on top of the "recent activity" box.  Basically I want the margin on top of the text to change based on the browser window height, keeping the text at the bottom of the browser window.

Comment: `position: fixed; bottom: 0`

Comment: @adeneo I want it to be at the bottom of the page, but still be liquid (not `fixed`) when scrolled.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42301/581760

Comment: @reinder I don't think you understand, see my update.

Comment: That is exactly what the question I linked to is answering. The only difference is that it's called a footer there and not "main content".

Comment: I tried what that linked post said, however that doesn't seem to be working, it's on http://www.jeffarries.com, if you want to check it out.

Comment: @reinder Sorry about the confusion, I've redone my post to display what I really need.

Comment: And now your question is of very low quality. Do some research, use google, show what you've tried with javascript. Nobody is going to do it for you

Comment: @reinder Ok, will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use archive this via CSS3 VH property [ View Port Height ]. For that you have to make one container and add its height to 100vh.
Here is the live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/8dptzvye/

```
*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
.container{height:100vh}
.container span{position:absolute; width:100%; display:block; left:0; bottom:0; text-aling:center; padding:20px; background:black; color:#fff}

<div class="container">
<div class="cover">Extra Infomation </div>
<span>here you can learn about me and my adventures</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `position: fixed`

EDIT

If you want to change the `margin` based on the window size, you can use jquery's `resize`

```
$(window).resize(function () { /* change margin of element */ });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but I want it to be at the bottom of the page, but still be liquid (not fixed, scrollable) when scrolled.

Comment: You want it to remain at the bottom of the page everytime or some other experience? May be it is not clear from the question what you ned

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I've redone my post to display what I really need.

Comment: @JeffArries - You shouldn't be changing your question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @BSMP Ok, I will revert it!

Comment: Saw Edit, how do I change the margin? I don't know JavaScript well, thanks!